# Gallio can't run test from console

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, odata, wcf-data-services

i'm having a problem running an integration test through Gallio.
The test works fine when I run it with Testdrive.NET or through the integrated Gallio in Visual Studio. When I'm trying to run it through the console (like our nant scripts do) it fails. The message received is this:

> [failed] Test
>   TenForce.Execution.Api2.OData.Tests/AttachmentIntegrationTests/Att
>   achmentUpload Execute
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The
>   communication objec t, System.Data.Services.DataServiceHost, cannot be
>   used for communication becaus e it is in the Faulted state.    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.System.IDisposable.Dispose()    at
>   TenForce.Execution.Api2.OData.Tests.IntegrationTests.AttachmentIntegration
>   Tests.AttachmentUpload() in
>   D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\Documents\Developme
>   nt\Projects\Robinson\TenForce.Execution.Api2.OData.Tests\IntegrationTests\Attach
>   mentIntegrationTests.cs:line 83
>
> Disposing the test runner. Stop time: 16:45 (Total execution time:
>   20,515 seconds)
>
> 1 run, 0 passed, 1 failed, 0 inconclusive, 0 skipped

The complete commandline is the following:

> Gallio.Echo.exe /r:IsolatedProcess TenFor
>   ce.Execution.Api2.OData.Tests.dll
>   /f:Namespace:TenForce.Execution.Api2.OData.Tes ts.IntegrationTests

I have no idea what is causing this problem in Gallio. It works from VS but not on the build agent or console. The source code of the test is this:

```
using System.Data.Services;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace TenForce.Execution.Api2.OData.Tests.IntegrationTests
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ServiceModel.Web;
    using MbUnit.Framework;
    using Objects;
    using Helpers;
    using Test.Attributes;

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>This class contains all the integration tests to verify the correct working conditions for attachment entities.</para>
    /// </summary>
    public class AttachmentIntegrationTests : BaseIntegrationTest
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// <para>This test will try to create a new attachment on an item using a local file.</para>
        /// </summary>
        [Test, MaxDuration]
        public void AttachmentUpload()
        {
            #region Test Preparation

            // Prepare a Workspace
            var workspace = CreateWorkspaceObject();
            Assert.IsTrue(Factory.CreateApi().Workspaces.Create(workspace), "Expected the test workspace to be created.");

            // Prepare a List
            var list = CreateList();
            list.Workspace = workspace;
            list.ItemType = new ItemType {Id = 5};
            Assert.IsTrue(Factory.CreateApi().Lists.Create(list), "Expected the test list to be created.");

            // Prepare an Item.
            var itemFields = new List<ItemField>
                                     {
                                         new ItemField {FieldId = "SF19", Type = "List", ValueId = list.Id},
                                         new ItemField {FieldId = "SF2", Type = "Title", Value = string.Format("I {0}", DateTime.Now)},
                                         new ItemField {FieldId = "SF4", Type = "AssignedTo", ValueId = 1}
                                     };
            var item = new Item { ItemFields = itemFields.ToArray() };
            Assert.IsTrue(Factory.CreateApi().Items.Create(item), "Expected the test item to be created.");

            #endregion

            using (var host = new DataServiceHost(typeof (Web.Api), new[] {BaseUri}))
            {
                // Start the host
                host.Open();

                // Create a new WebClient to create a call to the attachments resource
                var client = new ODataClient {BaseUri = BaseUri, Username = "sadmin", Password = string.Empty};

                // Send the file contents to the service using the correct url.
                string response = client.UploadAttachment(GetTestFileLocation("ReportingTest.xls"), item.Id);
                var parser = new ODataParser();
                parser.LoadResponse(response);

                // Fetch the Id of the Attachment, this should be greater than 0.
                int attachmentId = parser.GetEntityId();
                Assert.IsTrue(attachmentId > 0, "Expected the Id to be greater than zero.");

                // Verify if the item is coupled to the correct Item.
                response = client.GetResource(string.Format("Attachments({0})/Item", attachmentId));
                parser.LoadResponse(response);
                int itemId = parser.GetEntityId();
                Assert.IsTrue(itemId == item.Id, "Expected the linked item to have a matching Id.");

                // Change the filename of the uploaded file and verify whether the file is properly renamed.
                client.UpdateProperty(string.Format("Items({0})/Attachments({1})/Filename/$value", itemId, attachmentId), "uploaded_excel.xls");

                // Verify if the changes made it to the database.
                Attachment att = Factory.CreateApi().Attachments.Read(attachmentId);
                Assert.AreEqual("uploaded_excel.xls", att.Filename, "Expected the data to be changed on the entity.");
                Assert.IsTrue(System.IO.File.Exists(Factory.CreateApi().Attachments.GetAttachmentPath(att, false)), "Expected the file to be present on the hard drive.");

                // Close the host properly
                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something in regards to hosting the DataService in the unit test?

**EDIT 1**
Running the following command:

> netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:60000/ODataService/
>   user=administrator

Solved part of the problem. I can now run the test without problems fine on my development system through the console, but the build agents still can't run the test. They push the following output:

> failed Execute System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an
>   error: (500) Internal Server Error. Status: ProtocolError Response:
>   System.Net.HttpWebResponse    at System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(Uri
>   address, String method, String fileName)    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(Uri address, String fileName)    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(String address, String fileName)    at
>   TenForce.Execution.Api2.OData.Tests.Helpers.ODataClient.UploadAttachment(String
>   path, Int32 itemId) in
>   c:\Robinson\trunk\Projects\Robinson\TenForce.Execution.Api2.OData.Tests\Helpers\ODataClient.cs:line
>   69    at
>   TenForce.Execution.Api2.OData.Tests.IntegrationTests.AttachmentIntegrationTests.AttachmentUpload()
>   in
>   c:\Robinson\trunk\Projects\Robinson\TenForce.Execution.Api2.OData.Tests\IntegrationTests\AttachmentIntegrationTests.cs:line
>   89
>   ------- Stdout: ------- Unable to read configuration section
>   common/logging.  Using no-op implemenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me quite some time to figure this out, but the problem is not Gallio.
The problem is the toolkit used to develop the OData service. This toolkit is not able to run from a console hosting environment.

After moving the service to a remote server and writing tests to call the functions remotely and parse the responses, we got the intended behavior working.